# Putting arguments in react component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the answer to one of my react course's problem.

```
import React from 'react';
const useState = React.useState;

export default function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
    const onButtonClick = () => {
        setCount(count+1);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Click Me!</button>
            
            <h1>Current Count: {count}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In react, why does it cause error when you do put argument in onButtonClick function.

```
    const onButtonClick = (count) => {
        setCount(count+1);
    };
```

Shouldn't we need to put count as argument in order to use it into function? What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused since the callback will try to add a Number with an Object. The first argument in your event callback is the [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) Object. If you want to make your callback accept an argument, you should rewrite your JSX like so:

```
<button onClick={(event) => onButtonClick(event, count)}>Click Me!</button>
```

In your event callback you can use this argument like this:

```
const onButtonClick = (event, count) => {
  setCount(count+1);
};
```

The above is not needed since the function is inside the [local scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) of your functional component. This means it can access the `count` variable, unlike many other programming languages.